# Creating sub-lists with Wagtail RichText streamfield

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I'm building a website using the Wagtail CMS for Django. I'm currently using a RichText streamfield block to add content to a page. Content editors can use the list icon in the WYSIWYG editor to add a list to a page. However, as a content editor, I'm not sure how to add a sublist to an unordered list. E.g.

- one list item
- two list items

  - one sublist item
  - two sublist items
- three list items

In other WSYSIWYG editors (like Google docs and etherpad) I would start a sublist by hitting tab. Hitting tab seems to move the focus away from the RichText streamfield. Adding spaces after a bullet doesn't seem to help either. How do wagtail developers expect content editors to create sub-lists?

I can just copy-paste from an HTML page that has an unordered list, but that may baffle my less-technical content editors. I love how user-friendly the Wagtail web interface is, and this is the first "huh?" moment I've had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/2212) with the rich text editor currently used by Wagtail ([hallo.js](http://hallojs.org/)). We're working on replacing it with something better, and hope to have this ready within the next couple of months. In the meantime, there are a couple of third-party packages available which provide alternative editors, such as [Wagtail TinyMCE](https://github.com/isotoma/wagtailtinymce) (which I can confirm *does* handle nested lists correctly).

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! I'll checkout Wagtail TinyMCE.

Answer (score 1):

Wagtail now uses [Draftail](https://www.draftail.org/), and nested lists are now available by doing what you tried with the old editor: cursor onto the line you want to indent, and use <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to indent or outdent the line.